# Why are empty levels in my factor tabulated after I assign NAs to missing values?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df` with a column `foo` containing data of type factor:

```
df <- data.frame("bar" = c(1:4), "foo" = c("M", "F", "F", "M"))
```

When I inspect the structure with `str(df$foo)`, I get this:

> Factor w/ 3 levels "","F",..: 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 2 ..

Why does it report 3 levels when there are only 2 in my data?

---

Edit:

There seems to be a missing value `""` that I clean up by assigning it `NA`.
When I call `table(df$foo)`, it seems to still count the "missing value" level, but finds no occurences:

```
  F M
0 2 2
```

However, when I call `df$foo` I find it reports only two levels:

```
Levels:  F M
```

How is it possible that `table` still counts the empty level, and how can I fix that behaviour?

Comment: Seems that you have empty values in some of your cells for `MF`. Try `table(df$MF)` to get the counts.

Comment: I suspect a missing value in the MF column. Are those 4 rows you posted the whole frame, or is there more?

Comment: Thanks! I checked if there were emptied cells but there are none.. If I do table(df$MF) I find this: 0, F 220, M 21. Where is that 0 coming from?

Comment: Please don't post images that are badly confidentialised. I suggest you have a peek at [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) regarding how to post great reproducible R [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)s

Comment: @Afke, I edited my answer. Please never remove the original question content, as all answers that were made prior to the edit then become incoherent. Instead, please edit the question and **append** any new observations. That way, your question will provide a more complete picture, and the answers will still be coherent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check whether your dataframe indeed has no missing values, because it does look to be that way. Try this:

```
# works because factor-levels are integers, internally; "" seems to be level 1
which(as.integer(df$MF) == 1)

# works if your missing value is just ""
which(df$MF == "")
```

You should then clean up your dataframe to properly refeclet missing values. A `factor` will handle `NA`:

```
df <- data.frame("rest" = c(1:5), "sex" = c("M", "F", "F", "M", ""))
df$sex[which(as.integer(df$sex) == 1)] <- NA
```

Once you have cleaned your data, you will have to drop unused levels to avoid tabulations such as `table` counting occurences of the empty level.

Observe this sequence of steps and its outputs:

```
# Build a dataframe to reproduce your behaviour
> df <- data.frame("Restaurant" = c(1:5), "MF" = c("M", "F", "F", "M", ""))
# notice the empty level "" for the missing value
> levels(df$MF)
[1] ""  "F" "M"

# notice how a tabulation counts the empty level;
# this is the first column with a 1 (it has no label because
# there is no label, it is "")
> table(df$MF)

  F M 
1 2 2

# find the culprit and change it to NA
> df$MF[which(as.integer(df$MF) == 1)] <- as.factor(NA)

# AHA! So despite us changing the value, the original factor
# was not updated! I wonder what happens if we tabulate the column...
> levels(df$MF)
[1] ""  "F" "M"

# Indeed, the empty level is present in the factor, but there are
# no occurences!
> table(df$MF)

  F M 
0 2 2 

# droplevels to the rescue:
# it is used to drop unused levels from a factor or, more commonly,
# from factors in a data frame.
> df$MF <- droplevels(df$MF)

# factors fixed
> levels(df$MF)
[1] "F" "M"

# tabulation fixed
> table(df$MF)

F M 
2 2
```

Comment: Thanks Oliver! I checked if I had missing values.. but both two top code lines return : integer(0). How is that possible? Thanks for you comment, I will edit the question to remove the bad images.

Comment: @Afke, I proposed quite a large edit to your question and title because I think it might be interesting to others. See if you like it, or feel free to edit it yourself! :)